# The relation between the intersection of two prime ideals and the annihilator of two elements of them

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $P,Q$ be two prime ideals such that $P\cap Q\neq{0}$. Let $a\in P\setminus Q$  and $b\in Q\setminus P$ such that $ab\neq0.$ Show that if $P\cap Q\subseteq \text{Ann}(a)\cup \text{Ann}(b)$, then $P\cap Q \subseteq \text{Ann}(a)$  or $P\cap Q \subseteq \text{Ann}(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Much of the given information is superfluous. In fact $J\subseteq A\cup B$ implies $J\subseteq A$ or $J\subseteq B$ for any ideals $J,A,B\triangleleft R$. This can be shown by contradiction. Suppose $J\subseteq A\cup B$ and

$$\begin{cases}x\in A\setminus B \\ y\in B\setminus A \\ x,y\in J\end{cases}$$

Then $x+y\in J\subseteq A\cup B$. Which of $A$ or $B$ could $x+y$ be in?

Comment: Is the assumption that $P, Q$ are prime unnecessary?

Comment: @Ink Nope. In fact this proves $J\subseteq A\cup B\implies J\subseteq A\vee J\subseteq B$ for any ideals $J,A,B$.

Comment: P,Q are prime ideals such that Z(R)=P∪Q

Answer (score 0):

NOTE, since a∈P∖Q and b∈Q∖P, then (a+b)∉P and (a+b)∉Q. Thus (a+b)∉Z(R).
Now, I want to prove this by a contradiction.
 Assume that there exists c∈Z^* (R)  such that c∈Ann(a)∩Ann(b), this implies ca=0 and cb=0. Hence c(a+b)=0, a contradiction since (a+b)∉Z^* (R). Thus ca=0 or cb=0. Hence c∈Ann(a)∖Ann(b)  or c∈Ann(b)∖Ann(a) ,and so P∩Q⊆Ann(a)\Ann(b)  or P∩Q⊆Ann(b)\Ann(a).

Comment: I just want to show what I meant a bout the intersection being in Ann(a) or Ann(b) but not both.